# formate date in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am getting date from api 2021-03-01T01:15:18.000Z. I want to show it as Mar 01,01:15 AM

I am using

```
{moment(item.issued_on).format("MMM DD, HH:mm A")}
```

but the above code is giving me Mar 01,06:65 AM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your time seems to be in UTC format, hence you're getting different value depending on your locale.

Use .UTC() of moment if you want to ignore the locale

```
var now = moment('2021-03-01T01:15:18.000Z').utc().format("MMM DD, HH:mm A")
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/as05ujvr/